# Solving polynomial of three variables to get radius in Java

Tags: java, polynomial-math

I have three variables as seen here:

```
float a = N * N + Q * Q - 1;
float b = 2 * M * N - 2 * N * x1 + 2 * P * Q - 2 * Q * y1 + 2 * s1 * r1;
float c = x1 * x1 + M * M - 2 * M * x1 + P * P + y1 * y1 - 2 * P * y1 - r1 * r1;
```

And I would like to find the root of the quadratic equation since I want to use it to get the radius of a circle.

Is there a built in function in Java to solve this?  A nice one liner would be great.

Comment: what is the quadratic equation here?

Comment: Are you asking for Java's [`Math.sqrt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)) function?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look to [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in Java SE function to solve equation. You could solve it on your own or find some 3rd party libs, like Apache Commons Math, e.g.

You can use `PolynomialFunction` class for that and `BisectionSolver` for finding roots

> Implements the bisection algorithm for finding zeros of univariate
>   real functions. The function should be continuous but not necessarily
>   smooth.

For reference - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html take a look into **4.3 Root-finding** section